# user defined pdb functions

Tags: user-defined-functions, pdb

How to define the `pdb` equivalent to this `gdb` snippet:

```
define go
    set $i = 1000
    while $i
        step
        set $i = $i - 1
    end
end
```

I've tried the following but failed:

```
def go(): set $i = 1000; while $i: step; set $i = $i - 1
go()
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
*** NameError: name 'go' is not defined
```

Another (even simpler) failed attempt:

```
def go(): while 1: step
go()
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
*** NameError: name 'go' is not defined
```